# Is it possible to export a shader editor nodegroup to a script/text file?

Tags: scripting, node-editor, shaders

Looking to export an extremely complex nodegroup to a script for a framework test. If i can export the nopdegroup to code, then i would be able to use another program to fill in the parameters of the nodes in the nodegroup based on numbers from an existing api. Then i will be able to re-import that script with updated parameters. (i need hundreds of these updated nodegroups. Thats why im trying to automate it). The only lead ive had on this automatic exporting to python script was something called PyNodes but there is very little documentation on it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Sure. Question is *how* it should look like... json?

Comment: Hello, you definitely can parse every node of your material and then somehow export it into a text format, but you will have first to define how it will be structured. Short answer is yes, but there currently is no built-in way to do it. How experienced are you with Python ?

Comment: to be honest, not very experienced at all. All ive seen is a tutorial on how to build nodegroups with the text editor, so i assumed that it could work in reverse as well. Here is the blend file with the nodegroup in it btw. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r0ubFx9F3PTdfkZ7MOFgjHv6YD9UoU8l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If the tutorial is freely available, could you share a link so I can see what's up ?

Comment: yep. Here it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQW2EnId1Ks